# What is appropriate form for company employees to be involved on WPSE?

Tags: discussion

I got a private inquiry from hosting provider about having their employees involved with monitoring and answering hosting-related questions on WPSE.

What are the appropriate way for employees to be involved and helpful, without crossing boundaries into unwanted promotion?

Rather than discussing it in private I urged to have this on meta and we agreed on me asking this in generic form and self-answering. Naturally any and all other input is welcomed as always.

Answer (score 11):

While WPSE is perfectly friendly to commercial entities and professional reputation building (most of my own professional reputation are WPSE points :), it is still delicate balance between individual participation and explicit or implicit promotion.

This is not complete turn key guide to such participation, but from my experience I can identify several foundational aspects, which are very important to get right for having and maintaining good connection with stack's community.

## Identification

Historically company profiles and excessively company-themed identities are frowned upon by community. People prefer to communicate with other people rather than faceless corporate entities.

Appropriate:

- individual account
- professional/employer information in profile
- disclosure in content where appropriate (for the sake of openness rather than self promotion)

Not [very] appropriate:

- company and especially shared account
- professional/employer signatures in content (signatures are forbidden in general)
- excessive mention of company where irrelevant

## Content

The content (questions and answers either) should strive for same high quality standards and wide applicability.

For hypothetical question (self or third party posted):

> How to resolve this issue with server configuration for WordPress?

Appropriate:

> From my experience [at our company doing relevant things] users commonly encounter this issue because [...] and I recommend to [...]

or

> At our company we are solving this issue via [open source] solution we created, which you can make use of by [...]

Not appropriate:

> Our hosting has unique super-duper feature that does this (AND brews coffee).

## Community involvement

There are essentially no formal rules *what* is spam or excessive self promotion to be precisely abided by. Community determines instances of such by gut feeling and, believe me, community is way better at it than any set of rules or code analysis can possibly be.

Contribution that is genuinely helpful and open is rarely misunderstood.

However sometimes dialog and discussion is what it takes, so involvement here on meta is vital - both reactive (resolving inquiries or complaints from community) and proactive (asking community for information or opinion).

Comment: +1 and will sign that at any time and location: _"Community determines instances of such by gut feeling and, believe me, community is way better at it than any set of rules or code analysis can possibly be."_ but please leave the _"asking for opinion"_ part out. This is something that should happen in chat our outside this site.

Comment: @kaiser hm? Asking for opinion on meta about something that concerns whole stack is perfectly fine by me. Of course it _can_ be asked in chat before / as well, but nothing against asking it straight on meta. What it is for - discussion about site.

Comment: Read over _meta_ in there. Yes, it's ... ok. Not that it would be appropriate if asked for _"What do you think of our new product?"_

Answer (score 8):

**In-scope** sever configuration issues **specific to WordPress** encompass an extremely narrow scope.

General server configuration questions are out of scope. Recovering from hack questions are out of scope. WordPress has fairly minimal, straight-forward, minimum server requirements, and recommended file permissions. So, the use-case is going to be commensurately small.

That said: I think we would welcome contribution from those with WordPress experience at the host level could be quite valuable, especially when dealing with non-standard things such as nginx, IIS, etc.

I think that, as long as company affiliation is disclosed, there shouldn't be any issues regarding inappropriate commercial promotion, etc.